BIP32 Xpub + Child Secret - Examples to understand security
I have 5 Regtest examples: (h4, h3, h2, h1, h0), all using the same xpriv (Regtest), but at different levels of hardening from totally hardened to Completely unhardened. The secret/wif are derived at index 0.
I want to understand the (parent Xpub + child secret) => (Parent Xpriv) situation a little more concretely through examples.
From this data (h4 to h0), which of these cases would compromise the xprv/tprv?
Also, how easy is this, would someone be able to post the xprv/tprv here to demonstrate?
h4_xpub [b508ec00/86'/1'/0'/0']tpubDDv27PwryLjrhoJhVZyqqiCcDcSr2GQM3VAfjKgQRfW1NpP1GcJzX6m7Y5nfQ87FL88R7jTE31rnvmXXVtSxJELxPPRWEQiBor8Fvd1kfmP/*
h4_secret a798316b749a8e7d322bccfb9a4532b0f43636f07c07a79ec6e72950795876ca, wif cTCUzbjekDu2uSWEtdscuu4wogrrifBU8WhxuxbwTj8Hjp1d82UF


h3_xpub [b508ec00/86'/1'/0']tpubDDYsDs4LrSP61PcseRqfVebYGXar5UrJKXfwH798LWAkhZTpfN1cm9M5LkmZLTfXS41iwoX3XPK5xAZLYAa8MdD6mRqKQn3htZCUDYW4Kth/0/*
h3_secret 3ea0d6deb0a4996870c19799ec60d31ac23b64c8aa756d9583023b4d87ff5a6e, wif cPgSdw9Nm6JUng26GMapQNmoHFwaCebmTbFSbXPaLyKfSfgpeAcc


h2_xpub [b508ec00/86'/1']tpubDBLSrNKn7PmwwLQybN16iHKz2ZDjzLE3ugT3ece3mXvo3Hp6Znn7ujzRoFnny2h9WAMFUxeHQTHY8qXLheU4MuPWhhdcAaBgLU9nh62GXtp/0/0/*
h2_secret 2f673c0c9f5620e96fe69489b379ea31330b454d96808029877a4001c0b369cb, wif cPAr6rMKUUZW5ee6o4kKBYjxtFRkojL1G111PuCzARkTh2jvxJRJ


h1_xpub [b508ec00/86']tpubD9bJd1XJSMTj3tCL2uRyPbctsctZ9L2S23nTefawA7tLK8XRwjncc6qaNvMFks6raPPXCkQYae32sVnzJqZ4crzyarj6uoJxsTqnha4MYRc/1/0/0/*
h1_secret 289a10159015237c38250c40eea1439cb27cfe33b8b342dd7be982231408d22c, wif cNwdGxRzYp34Vz4wmzdLRykCnz2sHDBmjPrkFikyptkDzQXdbA3U


h0_xpub tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4YG7SgULkV1J8kkAsi3tcZG1WJDfALTe5eafze3gi3XMVJ8gGvCrnsJFvbXyNSjRyMwHJAcbKZkvuvwGYXFWDesKzrG1efsP/86/1/0/0/*
h0_secret 5641a5b6c1bab112b4de23ec7c7a65e4199512e62773d07fa1190637cab153a3, wif cQUNacgHgWZeRgJSPvyY89oiyt38T8tRMyoVWQVcgVU9EvybG4jx

